# Хранимые процедуры в PostgreSQL. Стоит ли, если пишешь на Python?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Подумываю о переводе части функционала из Web-приложения в хранимые процедуры Postgres.

Почему хочу: Оптимизация трафика и уменьшение кодовой базы реального приложения, так как есть такие функции, которые делают несколько запросов к БД.

Почему не хочу: С кодом который храниться в одном месте и с единым стилем проще работать.

Опишите пожалуйста в каком случае действительно стоит действительно прибегнуть к хранимым процедурам, когда ими начинают пользоваться? Какие с ними могут быть трудности?

Comment: Холиварная тема )

Comment: Не обязательно). Меня просто интересуют хорошие и плохие примеры, чтобы быть ко всему готовым заранее. В конце концов хранимые процедуры зачем-то были созданы и много кто их использует